# Should I remove swap file before shrinking partition? (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted, swap-file

I have a laptop which dual boots Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I have realized that I gave the Windows partition too little space when I installed Ubuntu so I want to shrink the Ubuntu partition (p4) and expand the Windows partition (p3).

The plan is to shrink p4 first from a Ubuntu Live session and expand p3 while logged in to Windows normally afterwards - this seems to be the standard procedure.

I have a 2GB swap file on the Ubuntu system. I seem to recall that a [swap file is kind of special](https://askubuntu.com/a/1017312/).

So the question is, when I perform the shrink operation with gparted from a USB live session will everything behave nicely or should I swapoff and remove the file first and recreate it after the operation? My concern being that gparted could create 'holes' in the file if it has to move the file during the shrinking (or other shenanigans that may cause me headaches - general tips are appreciated, I want to learn here).

My current partition scheme looks like this: [image: partition scheme]
I want to move 50GB from p4 to p3.

Comment: Great question. Remember to take backups before doing anything (preferably full disk image). Also, you won't be able to modify the Windows partition using OS booted from it. GParted will resize it fine though.